# manage hardware power supply

Tags: windows, power-management

How can I manage power supply? (if it's possible of course).

Since my charger doesn't supply the needed energy, I need to reduce/remove power from some devices in order to let my processor run full capacity. I have heard about powering down USB ports or something.

I use windows 8 on a DELL Inspiron n7110

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood your question, how'd you know that your charger _doesn't supply the needed energy_? Is it not the one that came with your laptop?

Comment: No, it isn't. It provides 90W and my laptop requires 130W. Plus, it goes full capacity on battery and not on charger.

Comment: This is impossible to achieve. You'll need to purchase a correct replacement charger for your laptop.

Comment: I also heard that on linux it's possible to manage power. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Windows (and no doubt Linux) automatically manages power to maximize efficiency. This is also true with modern computers, where the processor will automatically adjust its power draw according to the task at hand.

For example, it will consume more power when you're running a resource-intensive task, such as converting media files. In contrast, it will consume less power when you're only surfing the web.

However, you can't manually adjust the power management on a per device basis. There are no scripts or applications that you can use to tell, for example, the optical drive to consume less power, as devices are built and designed a power rating. What you can do is limit the number of peripherals attached to the laptop, e.g. an external storage drive. In addition, setting a profile where the device will automatically shutdown when idle at a certain duration (storage drives have this feature).

I'm not familiar with the implications of having a charger that doesn't meet the power requirements. Maybe someone more experienced here can put a light on this subject. In my opinion, this kind of setup isn't good in the long term.